# Restart my Phonegap app programmatically

Tags: cordova, restart

How can I programmatically restart my phonegap app?  I exit the app easily through navigator.app.exitApp(), but I would like it to restart immediately.

The reason I need this, is I have to restart it after the user chooses his user language from a selectbox menu.  The i18n immediately fires after the user updated his language choice, apart from 5 buttons on 1 page and a paragraph on another page.  Those 5 items remain in the previous language (also the language select menu layout gets completely destroyed for some reason), but when I restart the application they're all in the correct language.  There's either a very complicated problem with the i18n process, or I can backdoor solve it with the forced restart.

Ty,
Nutty

Comment: if you have an SPA with html5 routing urls, you might consider http://stackoverflow.com/a/37837377/82609

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I use the following:

```
location.reload();
```

Works a treat for me.

Paul

Comment: Oooo, I almost forgot about this question, since this functionality is removed in phase 1.  But it does seem to work, so in a later phase it might be of great use.  Thx

Comment: This reloads the index page but it doesn't actually close and restart the app. Useful in it's own right. However, I am still wondering if a full restart is possible...?

Answer (score 10):

Try this

```
navigator.app.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html", {wait:2000, loadingDialog:"Wait,Loading App", loadUrlTimeoutValue: 60000});
```

Bakri

Comment: Work#s perfect. Thanks!

Comment: This is for android right? What if i need to reload the ios app? what will be the path for iOS index.html?

Comment: I confirm (as expected) it does only work for Android :D

Comment: on IOS there has not `loadUrl` function inside `app`

Answer (score 10):

This works for iOS and Android (at least with 2016 platform versions).
It works also in SPA applications.

```
// keep startup url (in case your app is an SPA with html5 url routing)
var initialHref = window.location.href;

function restartApplication() {
  // Show splash screen (useful if your app takes time to load) 
  navigator.splashscreen.show();
  // Reload original app url (ie your index.html file)
  window.location = initialHref;
}
```

Comment: thanks for post just one line need to add after window.location = initialHref is that navigator.splashscreen.hide(); then it works perfect.

Comment: @Pritish it would be better if the hide() was called directly when your index.html page reloads, otherwise the splashscreen would not be seen during the whole time the app is restarting. But if it works for you fine it depends on how you integrate splash screen into your own app

Comment: thanks for valuable reply I will make changes in code as per your suggestions.