# How to restart cordova application

Tags: angularjs, cordova, cordova-plugins

I use AngularJS and Cordova build app android. 
I want have a button with action restart app. 
`How to restart this app?`

Comment: Why would you like to restart your application? Don't you simply need to reload your homepage?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Restart my Phonegap app programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477887/restart-my-phonegap-app-programmatically)

Answer (score 2):

Whatever you exactly want, you can have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477887/restart-my-phonegap-app-programmatically#15649905) which gives you a very simple answer:

> `location.reload()`;

As stated in the comments, it does not properly restart your application (meaning completely stop and then start it again) but it should do the trick most of the time.

Comment: @Tuhin You are right. It am not used to it but I should. The answer was so easy to found.