# SAPUI5 - Redirect Logout to Kapsel Login Plugin

Tags: redirect, sapui5, logout, web-ide

I’m developping an hybrid app in SAPUI5. I insert a logout button that execute standard method *doDeleteRegistration* and it work well.

The problem that I can't fix is redirect, after logout, to login page.
The login is done with Kapsel Logon Plugin.

Someone can help me?
Thanks in advance,
Mavhart

Comment: Have you tried [`location.reload()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15649905/5477321) to restart the app?

Comment: Hi Schnoedel, thx for you reply.
I've solved, after call method sap.Logon.core.deleteRegistration is been enough call sap.Logon.core.loadStartPage!

Comment: Good find! Thanks for sharing the solution with us!

Comment: loadStartPage takes me straight back into the app, bypassing the login page.